# How to get a record in database with sqlite3?

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm want to get a specific record in my database I tried:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?', (str(self.email),))
```

it always returns None.

Also tried

```
cursor.execute("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email = ?", (self.email,))
```

and this gave an error

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably
>   unsupported type

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: `users.email` is a TEXT column and "email" means an email address, like `someone@example.com`

The result of the second query indicates that `self.email` is not a string.

The result of the first query indicates that after `self.email` is coerced to a string,  the result does not match any `email` in the user table.

From what is posted,  one can only assume what `self.email` *isn't*.

Comment: Yes, users.email is a TEXT but when it didn't convert it to string it gives an error about type which make me confused

Comment: What type is `self.email`. That is the root of the problem.

Comment: It's an Entry. I'm implementing a registration form which contain an email field so I store value that user entered in this variable ```self.email = Entry(self.register_window)```

Comment: I can't know what `Entry` is, but it's not an email address.

Comment: The ```Entry```  is a widget used to provde the single line text-box to accept a value from the user. And it accepts a text strings from the user.

Comment: Which type should email address be?

Comment: For the sql, the parameter you pass should be a string. Suggest you consult the doc to see how you get the textual information from the Entry widget.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that.